# Is PhantomJS supposed to load local js for a local html file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to load a local html, which is loading a local js file, so the paths are like this:

```
/Users/me/html/page.html
/Users/me/html/page.js
```

and page.html includes the `page.js` file, and I can verify that by loading `file:///Users/me/html/page.html` and see the `console.log`ing in the console for that page.

Now this js file is also merely adding a attribute to the body for testing this issue, which works normally.  When I load this html file with PhantomJS however the js file does not change the DOM (ie does not add the attribute to the `body`).

The js file is loaded last on the html file, so it is at the bottom of the page:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="page.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Again loading this page normally it works, but with a phantom.js script it does not:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var system = require("system");
var args = system.args;
var pageURL = args[1];

page.open(pageURL, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success')
  {
    console.log(status);
  }
  else
  {
    var result = page.evaluate(function()
    {
      return document.body.getAttribute("data-changed") || "not found";
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

the `page.js` looks like this:

```
document.body.setAttribute("data-changed", "true");
console.log("changed the page with js!")
```

So, is PhantomJS supposed to run js from the page being opened? or not? and if it is then what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did a quick test and it does work with PhantomJS v2.0.1dev, logging `true`. What is your output/behaviour?

Comment: Your [HTML is invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element). There cannot be a script element under root. Put it into body or head.

Comment: you have more rep than I, you can press the edit button too.

Comment: @Vaviloff I have the same weird stuff going on. It is logging true, but I keep getting "Can't find variable: $"

Comment: @Carine, please post a question, it seems you have a different html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS pages are not directly aware of the filesystem, and the `page.js` script is practically invisible to your page even though they are in the same directory. Instead of including the script directly in your HTML, you can use Phantom's [`injectJs`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) to dynamically inject the script once the page is created, and before you evaluate it. `injectJs` will accept an absolute local path to the script, a path *relative* to the Phantom script itself, or a remote script, but not one that is relative to the page.

Modify your `page.open` callback like so:

```
page.open(pageURL, function(status) {
    ...
    else {
        // try to inject page.js
        if ( page.injectJs('/Users/me/html/page.js') ) {
            // page.js was injected, so evaluate:
            var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.body.getAttribute("data-changed") || "not found";
            });
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
});
```